# $L^p$-norm minimization under linear constraints: Does the optimum depend on $p$?

Tags: normed-spaces, lp-spaces, nonlinear-optimization

Consider the following norm minimization program:

\begin{align}
\label{1}
&\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d} &&\lVert x - x_0 \rVert_p^p &(1)\\
&\text{subject to } &&Ax-b \ge 0
\end{align}
Here, $\lVert \cdot \rVert_p$ is the $L^p$-norm, with $p \ge 1.$
Is the following statement true?

*If $x^*$ is a solution to (1) for some $p \ge 1$, then $x^*$ is also a solution for any $q \ge 1$.*

I guess this boils down to showing that the minimal distance between a hyperplane $X$ and the point $x_0$ is always obtained in the same point $x^* \in X$, regardless of which $L^p$-norm is being used.
When I make sketches for the case $d=2$, the statement "looks right", but I could not come up with a proof. Maybe the Hölder inequality can be used in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right, the statement is not true. You can sketch the simple following example on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $x_0=(1,1)^T$ and 
$$A= \begin{pmatrix}
       1 & 0 \\
       \frac{2}{5}&\frac{1}{5}
     \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then it is easy to see for $p=1$, the minimum is attained at $(2,1)^T$, however for $p=2$, the minimum is attained at $(\frac{9}{5},\frac{7}{5})^T$. The reason is when we consider distance, $p=2$ corresponds to a ball, while $p=1$ corresponds to a square.

Comment: Thank you! I am assuming you meant to set $b=(0,1)$ (or $b=(1,1)$ or something similar)?

Comment: @Sorry, I mean $b=(1,1)^T$.